Cookies visible in response but not getting saved
I am facing a problem that when I send request to my server for signin, I am able to see cookies in the network tab as response but it is not visible in application tab i.e. it does not get saved. I am using MERN stack for the project. Can someone help me out
Signin function (backend controller)
const UserSignin = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        const userSchema = zod.object({
            email: zod.string().email(),
            password: zod.string().min(8)
        });
        const result = userSchema.safeParse({ email, password });
        if (result.error) {
            return res.status(411).json({
                message: `Incorrect inputs: ${result.error}`
            }); 
        }
        const user = await User.findOne({ email, password });
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(411).json({
                message: `Incorrect credentials`
            });
        }
        const jwt_token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, JWT_SECRET);
        return res.status(200).cookie('authcookie', jwt_token, {
            maxAge: 900000,
            httpOnly: true
        }).json({
            message: "User logged in successfully",
            token: jwt_token
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: error.message
        });
    }
}

Making signin request(from frontend):
    const handleLogin= (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user/signin', { email, password })
    .then( response=> {
    console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error=>{
    console.log(error);
    })
    }


the request looks cross origin - you should include credentials in the request - sorry, don't know how to use axios to do that, I know you can though - it's documented I'm sure

Typically, you must use HTTPS to solve many cookie problems, also see my blog post her https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/
